# How to make this slider autoplay?

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I am using [this really cool pure css slider](https://github.com/drygiel/csslider) in one of my projects it works super fine but the thing is i want the slides to auto play in the project, i don't know much about js, here is my code. Please have a look and suggest something. I have tried [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr). but it didn't worked.

```
<div class="csslider">
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1" checked />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_N" />
     <ul>
         <li>Content of slide 1</li>
         <li>Content of slide 2</li>
         <li>Content of slide 3</li>
         <li>Content of slide 4</li>
         <li>Content of slide N</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="arrows">
         <label for="slides_1"></label>
         <label for="slides_2"></label>
         <label for="slides_3"></label>
         <label for="slides_4"></label>
         <label for="slides_N"></label>
         <label for="slides_1" class="goto-first"></label>
         <label for="slides_N" class="goto-last"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="navigation">
        <div>
            <label for="slides_1"></label>
            <label for="slides_2"></label>
            <label for="slides_3"></label>
            <label for="slides_4"></label>
            <label for="slides_N"></label>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and here is the **cssslider.css** file

```
.csslider {
  -moz-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.csslider > input {
  display: none;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -900%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -800%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -700%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -600%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -500%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.csslider > ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  border: 0px solid #3a3a3a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.csslider > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  vertical-align: top;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}
.csslider > ul > li.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.csslider > .navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider > .navigation > div {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > .navigation label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #3a3a3a;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  background: #71ad37;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.csslider > .arrows {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider.inside .navigation {
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.csslider.inside .navigation label {
  border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(1):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(2):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(3):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(4):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(5):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(6):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(7):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(8):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(9):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(10):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(11):after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.csslider > .arrows {
  position: absolute;
  left: -31px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.csslider > .arrows label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  padding: 13px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 1px #3a3a3a;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
}
.csslider > .arrows label:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 0 2px #71ad37;
  margin: 0 0px;
}
.csslider > .arrows label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
}
.csslider.infinity > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-last,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(0),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(1),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.csslider.infinity > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-first,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(10),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(11),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(12) {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
/*#region MODULES */
/*#endregion */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like the time is come to add javascript..

```js
var slidesCbx = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=slides]');
setInterval(function(){
  var activeSlide;
  for(var i=0;i<slidesCbx.length;i++){
    if(slidesCbx[i].checked) activeSlide = (i+1)%slidesCbx.length;
    slidesCbx[i].checked = false;
  }
  slidesCbx[activeSlide].checked=true;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.csslider {
  -moz-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
.csslider > input {
  display: none;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -900%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -800%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -700%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -600%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -500%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -400%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -300%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
.csslider > ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  border: 0px solid #3a3a3a;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.csslider > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  vertical-align: top;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}
.csslider > ul > li.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.csslider > .navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider > .navigation > div {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
.csslider > .navigation label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #3a3a3a;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.csslider > .navigation label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  background: #71ad37;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.csslider > .arrows {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.csslider.inside .navigation {
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.csslider.inside .navigation label {
  border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
}
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(1):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(2):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(3):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(4):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(5):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(6):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(7):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(8):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(9):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(10):after,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(11):after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.csslider > .arrows {
  position: absolute;
  left: -31px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.csslider > .arrows label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  padding: 13px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 1px #3a3a3a;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
}
.csslider > .arrows label:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 0 2px #71ad37;
  margin: 0 0px;
}
.csslider > .arrows label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
}
.csslider.infinity > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-last,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(0),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(1),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.csslider.infinity > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-first,
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(7):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(8):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(9):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(10),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(10):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(11),
.csslider > input:nth-of-type(11):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(12) {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
/*#region MODULES */
/*#endregion */
```

```html
<div class="csslider">
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1" checked />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4" />
     <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_N" />
     <ul>
         <li>Content of slide 1</li>
         <li>Content of slide 2</li>
         <li>Content of slide 3</li>
         <li>Content of slide 4</li>
         <li>Content of slide N</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="arrows">
         <label for="slides_1"></label>
         <label for="slides_2"></label>
         <label for="slides_3"></label>
         <label for="slides_4"></label>
         <label for="slides_N"></label>
         <label for="slides_1" class="goto-first"></label>
         <label for="slides_N" class="goto-last"></label>
     </div>
     <div class="navigation">
        <div>
            <label for="slides_1"></label>
            <label for="slides_2"></label>
            <label for="slides_3"></label>
            <label for="slides_4"></label>
            <label for="slides_N"></label>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```